# How to properly get <i> elements inside a <p> element in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to get the text from the i (italic) elements inside a paragraph with
this code:

```
$('p').each(function(j, element){
    if($(element).is("i")){
        console.log("The value is: "+$(element).text());
    }
});
```

But the flow never enters the if condition.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hvae you tried `$('p i').text()`

Comment: It never enters into the if condition because `$('p')` returns P elements, not the child elements. So the test `$(element).is('i')` is always false. As others say `$('p i')` will work.

Comment: (Not Relevant) - If you're using <i> tag, just to create an italic look, then I recommend you the <em> tag instead of <i>. Both italic and bold text in a webpage means something other that just to create a look.

According to the HTML 5 specification, the <b> tag should be used as a LAST resort when no other tag is more appropriate. The HTML 5 specification states that headings should be denoted with the <h1> to <h6> tags, emphasized text should be denoted with the <em> tag, important text should be denoted with the <strong> tag, and marked/highlighted text should use the <mark> tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('p').each(function(j, element){
    if($(element).is("i")){
        console.log("The value is: "+$(element).text());
    }
});
```

inside the each() handler `element` refers to the `p` element so it will never satisfy the element selector condition `i`(`$(element).is("i")`) so the if condition will never get executed

If you want to fetch the value of `i` element with in `p` then use descendant selector

```
$('p i').each(function(j, element){
    console.log("The value is: "+$(element).text());
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use `i` in selector

```
$('p i')
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use descendant selector

```
 $('p i')
```

Or `.find()` method

```
 $('p').find("i")
```

To fetch the value of `i` element with in `p` you can use either of above methods

```
$('p').find("i").each(function(j, element){
    console.log("The value is: "+ $(element).text());
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use **[find()](http://api.jquery.com/find/)**

```
 $('p').find("i")
```

For example

```
$('p').find("i").each(function(j, element)
{
    // DO Somthing
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$('p').each(function(j){
    if($(this).children('i')){
        console.log("The value is: "+$(this).text());
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$('p').children('i').each(function(j, element){
  console.log("The value is: "+$(element).text());
});
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/JyxL4/